# Can we have a instance of a interface?

Tags: interfaces, transfer

I came across this code, I wanted to know what exactly IERC20(token address) is signifying here whether it is the instance of token or just the reference to the contract of token to which the user is transferring the amount.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is creating a reference to an existing instance of the contract. The `tokenAddress` is an address which holds a contract.

The interface says what kind of functionality the address supports (supposedly). So once you create this kind of reference, you have type-safe access to the functionality defined in the interface.

Bear in mind that you can write whatever you want in the interface and the reference is still created just fine. But if you try to use some functionality which doesn't exist at the address, through the reference, you'll get errors.

So, no, you can't have an instance of an interface, but you can have a reference to an already existing instance.